# How do I add my app's notification sound to the notification sound list?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, ringtone

I want the user to be able to choose a notification sound for my app so I use the code below:

```
Intent ringtoneIntent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
ringtoneIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, false);
ringtoneIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
ringtoneIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
ringtoneIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Choose");
ringtoneIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
fragment.startActivityForResult(ringtoneIntent, REQUEST_RINGTONE);
```

Unfortunately, my app's own notification sound isn't in the list. Google Hangouts, Calendar, and Facebook *are* in the list. I assume these programs have done something to register with android, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First copy your file to the rigntones folder (See Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)

Then register the sound:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, nameOfSound);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, yourAppName);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

One very easy and straightforward solution would be simply copying your sound files to [`Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS) or [`Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_RINGTONES).